# Why am I getting undefined references with bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

I am using texlive on ubuntu and getting

> LaTeX Warning: Citation `texbook' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.

And in the output file no reference is showing. I have followed the examples from http://www.bibtex.org/Using/ and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KS9GvK7cvmo

My main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\title{ demo bibtex}
\author{kazi}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

some claim \cite{texbook}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

And my refs.bib file:

```
@book{texbook,
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The {\TeX} Book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional}
}

@book{latex:companion,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Gossens
            and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle
            and Chris Rowley},
  year = {2004},
  title = {The {\LaTeX} Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
  edition = {2}
}

@book{latex2e,
  author = {Leslie Lamport},
  year = {1994},
  title = {{\LaTeX}: a Document Preparation System},
  publisher = {Addison Wesley},
  address = {Massachusetts},
  edition = {2}
}
```

Comment: Did you actually run bibtex? You need to run, pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex or similar.

Comment: As daleif says: You need to run BibTeX on your document. A full compilation sequence would then involve LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for more details. Your editor probably has a button to do that.

Comment: Thanks. First I ran "pdflatex main" then this happened so did not go forward. Now it is okay, I tried "pdflatex main && bibtex main && pdflatex main && pdflatex main". It worked

Comment: Even better: just use `latexmk -pdf file.tex` and it will run them for you